# How to impove speed of the algorithm

Tags: c#, .net, optimization

I have this method at each iteration of which, the odd characters of the string are combined and wrapped to its beginning, and the even characters are wrapped to the end. `source` is the source string. `count` is the count of iterations.

```
        public static string Shuffle(string source, int count)
        {
        for (long i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            source = string.Join(string.Empty, source.Where((v, j) => j % 2 == 0))
            + string.Join(string.Empty, source.Where((v, j) => j % 2 != 0));
        }

        return source;
        }
```

Everything works fine, but when `count = int.MaxValue` calculations take too long. How can you change the algorithm to speed up the computation?

Comment: You're creating a lot of garbage.  String is immutable.  I'd go with an array instead.

Comment: Using a `StringBuilder` would likely be faster (I suspect you are spinning off so much garbage, the GC is slowing you down). However there's nothing convenient like `string.Join` (though might want to write something similar). If you can calculate how big your result is going to be up front, use the constructor that takes a capacity.

Comment: I stand corrected. You're right about it being slow for 2 billion iterations (I gave up after 5 minutes).  Using a `StringBuilder` is faster for a low number of iterations. But...  At 20 million, your code takes nearly a minute.  While using a pre-allocated `StringBuilder` takes about 2.5x that time, and then throws an out of memory exception on the call to `StringBuilder.ToString` (which is weird, this is an `AnyCPU` build (without `Prefer 32 bit`).  I'm curious why you want to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings are immutable, you can avoid their creation inside the loop by using a character array  (do it in the C way). *Shuffle2("ABCDEFGHIKKLMNOP", int.MaxValue)* took 67 sec. But it's a waste of energy, this algorithm is periodic with a periodic length of length(text) (at even string length). Shuffle("ABCD", x) will give the same result as Shuffle("ABCD", x+4)

```cs
public static string Shuffle2(string source, int count)
{
    char[] text = source.ToCharArray();
    char[] buffer = new char[source.Length];

    for (long i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        int j = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < text.Length; k += 2, j++) buffer[j] = text[k];  // Odd characters at index 0, 2, 4, ...
        for (int k = 1; k < text.Length; k += 2, j++) buffer[j] = text[k];  // Place even characters after the odd characters in the buffer.
        buffer.CopyTo(text, 0);  // Maybe there is a tricky exchange in your original array where you don't need a buffer.
    }

    return new string(text);
}
```